# MPAndroidChart PieChart

Tags: java, android, mpandroidchart

In my project, use the library [MaterialDesign](https://github.com/navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary). When I add also the library MPchart, I get this error and do not understand what's wrong. Thank You

```
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/nineoldandroids/animation/Animator$AnimatorListener;
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:303)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
```

build.gradle of MaterialDesign Library:

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.+'
  compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
}
```

and build.gradle of project:

```
dependencies {
  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
  compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.0'
  compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.+'
  compile project(":MaterialDesign")
  compile project(":MPChartLib")
  compile files('libs/opencsv-2.4.jar')
}.
```

If I remove the dependence, I get other errors.
What can I do?

Comment: This means that you have two libraries that share the same dependency (`Animator.class`) and you're importing both of them. Check the JAR files and gradle dependencies that you're adding to your project to make sure that the file that defines `Animator` is only included once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are declaring a dependency `com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.+` in both `MPChartLib` and in your project. This is what's causing the problem.

Try to remove the dependency from your project but leave it in MPChartLib so that the dextool only sees it once. Your new build.gradle would look like this:

```
dependencies {
  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
  compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.0'
  compile project(":MaterialDesign")
  compile project(":MPChartLib")
  compile files('libs/opencsv-2.4.jar')
```

}

Also do the same for the Android support library. It should be declared only once or you'll get similar errors.

Comment: This should be the correct answer. MPAndroidChart uses the nineoldandroids library as well as some other library in your project.

Comment: Like I said in the first post, the library `'com.nineoldandroids: library: 2.4. +'` Is also used in `Material Design`. If I remove the dependency in my project does not change anything, because Material Design and `MPChartLib` use 'com.nineoldandroids: library: 2.4. +'. Do you have other suggestions?

Comment: Well concerning MPAndroidChart, what you could do is clone the repository instead of using the .jar file and remove the nineoldandroids from the libraries dependencies. Then Add the MPAndroidChart library to your project.